# Battery charger filter circuit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, filter, rectifier, full-bridge

I'm working on a project where I have to make a powerfull battery charger. And someone I'm working with told me that it is a good idea to have mains voltage connected to a full bridge rectifier and after that something like a Sallen-Key filter. But is there a reason for that? I do not get why it is an important feature.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried asking the person who told you to do that?

Comment: What were you thinking of doing instead? A rectifier and a filter aren't "features", they're design details. To explain why they're important, we'd have to know what the alternative is.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting way ahead of yourself.  Whether you need to monitor line voltage or not, and what filtering you need to apply to that if you do, are design details you are not ready for.

You have to start out with basic specs of *what* this "battery charger" is supposed to do before you can decide *how* it's supposed to do it.

Sit down and specify things like what line voltage range it will work with, whether PFC will be necessary, what type and quantity of batteries it will charge, how fast it should charge them, what tradeoffs you might want to make with capacity versus lifetime, etc, etc.